# Кастомная стилизация input,select,datalist

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка

При верстке  странички  наткнулся на один интересный элемент - `input`,`select` или database.

Не пойму, что это и как это сверстать, особенно стрелку с боку.
Подскажите, что это и как так сверстать

[image: input блока]

Вот полное изображение блока в pdf

[image: Весь блок]

Comment: Max M, как же мы Вам по картинке скажем? Давайте ссылку, или часть кода. Чисто визуально похоже на input обёрнутый селектом, чтобы можно было искать по словам.

Comment: @Max M Если ответ Вам был полезен, то не забудьте отметить его галочкой, как решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как самый простой пример, это можно сделать так:

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: red;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
}

label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 44px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: yellow;
}

label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid red;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: translate(-1rem, -0.6rem) rotate(45deg);
  right: 0;
  top: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

label select {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <select name="options">
    <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</label>
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

Comment: Отлично, красиво и полезно, на мой взгляд

Comment: Спасибо. Как select элемент это подходит.

Comment: @Sevastopol' хорошо бы, отмечать плюсами вопросы новичков и подсказывать им, как надо оформлять вопросы. Да и новички с репутацией больше +15 смогут отмечать ответы не только галочкой, но и плюсом